# Why did 'Milan' Actually Show up in end of movie Kahaani[2012]?

Tags: plot-explanation, kahaani

In the recently released Bollywood movie [Kahaani](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahaani), at the ending, why did "Milan" actually show up? Why did he want to Kill Vidhya Balan? How was he seriously affected by the things done by her? Why didn't he send just someone else instead of traveling all the way from wherever he was to Kolkata [West Bengal, India] to kill her?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia article for Kahaani](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahaani):

> Vidya calls Bhaskaran to tell him that she has got hold of sensitive
>   documents from Sridhar's office and if Bhaskaran helps Vidya find her
>   husband, she would hand over the documents to Bhaskaran. Bhaskaran
>   nonchalantly tells Vidya to contact the local police as he is not
>   associated with this. However, within a few minutes, Vidya gets a call
>   from an unknown number, warning her that she should hand over the
>   documents to the caller if she wishes to see her husband alive. Khan,
>   recognizing the voice, reveals the caller to be Milan Damji.

As per this conversation Bhaskaran got threatened so he sent Milan to meet Vidya because she asked to meet her husband who looks like Milan. So Bhaskaran's plan is to kill Vidya by her own husband(I mean Milan, who looks like her husband). So its order from Bhaskaran, his head, so that Milan personally went to meet her.